# Swift OS X 10.11 Cannot open SQLite3 database after a second app execution

Tags: swift, macos, sqlite

I use pure commands of the sqlite3 library,,, the first time you install the app, a method executes the sqlite3_open() method. It supposes to create the database. It actually creates it in a user folder (desktop folder in the mac os x) as showed in the log screen. After this step, it creates 2 tables and saves some data, and it completes this, with success.

the second time you run the app, it intents to open the database with the same method sqlite3_open(), but it presents the error showed in the image with code number 14.

After that, I made some research and found that the new version of sqlite uses 3 files (.sqlite, .sqlite-wal and .sqlite-shm)... After reading that, I started searching on how to create those 2 additional files at the moment of creating the first file  (the .sqlite file)... But I only found that all the tutorials copy those 3 files (previously created) to the references folder on the project, but they don't create it.

Continuing my search, found that there is an option to change the configuration of the sqlite in my app, to prevent using this wal option... I had to execute the command SQLITE_FCNTL_PRAGMA (maybe this is not used like I'm doing).

Please if you need more info that may help solving this issue please just let me know.

[image of Class method that opens/creates the Daatabase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8IHCA.png)

Edit: screenshot with the extended errcode resulting on error 14 with no more details.
[imglink](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UjYqR.png)

Comment: Try turning on extended result codes with `sqlite3_extended_result_codes()` and seeing what error you get.

Comment: Hi Doug. I tried the extended result codes command: in my case: 'sqlite3_extended_result_codes(self.db,1)', inputed before the 'if sqlite3_open_v2...'. but it throws the same 2 errors of the question's image. sqlite3_errmsg: 0x00007fff9a06bc0f. and sqlite3_errcode:14. Is there any other method to write more detailed error description??

Comment: Use `sqlite3_extended_errcode()` instead of `sqlite3_errcode()` to get the value. The extended result code is returned by `sqlite3_open_v2()` but you are throwing that away, and then getting the simple result code.

Comment: Thanks, I did it as you say, but it shows the same error: "14". P.D.: I can't upload images in here, so I'll edit the question to show the printscreen with the extended errcode